# UIView on top of a Static UITableViewController

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I am trying to develop a page-based registering flow and I need to have a "Next" `button` on each page. However, I am facing a problem which is adding this button to the `UITableViewController` that has static `tableView`. I tried many things, from adding subviews on `navigationController.view` to creating a `UIViewController` instead and using `ContainerView` to be able to use static `UITableView`. Also I want this button to move along with the keyboard.

Some of them actually/partially worked. But I can not decide which one is the best option. Apart from my experiments, I am wondering what you guys can suggest? Or what would you do in such case?

Thanks.

> EDIT

Some images on request.

[image: with open keyboard]
[image: with closed keyboard]

But please remember that, I am trying to do it using `UITableViewController` with static `UITableView`.

Answer (score 1):

`UITableViewControllers` only accept `UITableViews` as their top `view` outlet.

Maybe you should embed your view flow into an `UINavigationController` and make the right bar button item to your "next" button, and push the subsequent view controller onto the stack.

If you cannot use neither a navigation controller nor a normal `UIViewController` (because you need the static table view), you could try implementing a container view controller and embed the table view controller in it, see [Implementing a Container View Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html) - but that's a lot over overhead...

Comment: exactly yes and I am trying to go behind that. Your suggestion came to my mind and to be honest it would be really easy to do :) however, I have an UI design that I have to follow.

Comment: And as an example airbnb's application has a similar flow with the same feature.

Comment: Please check the additions to my answer. Since I do not know the airbnb application, I would suggest to post an image describing what you want.

Answer (score 1):

One of the possibilities is also `UIPageViewController`.
We had a project which also had page-based onboarding and registration. I used `UIPageViewController` which was embedded inside another `UIViewController`. That ViewController had **Back** and **Next** button, by clicking on those buttons you can programatically change currently visible ViewController inside `UIPageViewController`.

Comment: I thought this option also but, I kinda need to have seperate buttons on each page, so the transition would not be ruined beacuse of an overlay.

Comment: @Faruk I don't exactly know what you mean with overlay transitions, should see an example. But basically, if you hold all the buttons inside main view controller and perform transitions between child controllers (as UIPageViewController does), the transitions shouldn't impact your parent's elements.

Comment: I tried to imply a view window that stays on the screen all the time like status bar or navigation bar by saying overlay. And the transition is meant to be show segue animation. I had tried adding this button to navigation controller by `self.navigationController.addSubview(button)`, which I think pretty much the same thing from perspective of a user. I want to make the transition between pages(segues) smooth. Like I want these ViewControllers have their own button, so those buttons will move with the ViewControllers.

Comment: Oh okay, I thought you wanted few elements to be always there and not move. Anyway, this is what I meant. https://medium.com/@abhinavpraksh/ios-on-boarding-basic-swipeable-cards-diy-21ff0c87a713
I am not forcing you to use UIPageViewController, but just saying, that transitions can also be modified / custom when using it, so you can achieve segue like movements. Anyway, if it doesn't suit your case I understand. Hope you solve it nicely!